# Conditional formatting in Excel not working on cell content added dynamically by Microsoft Flow

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, microsoft-flow

I have set up a Flow to add content to a table in an Excel spreadsheet once a user makes a form submission.

I have applied conditional formatting to a column of this table (change fill colour according to cell content), however it is not working when the content is dynamically added. This rule ***does*** work, however, if the content is added manually (directly onto the Excel spreadsheet).

Is this a known problem for Excel? Are there any solutions that exist?

Thankyou.

Comment: So if you edit any cell after the flow update, does the conditional formatting update? What if you edit a cell within the affected table, does it only update that cell's CF or the whole table?

Comment: Oh and what happens to the CF if you save and/or close and reopen the file?

Comment: You didn't explain what type of data You re grabbing. That would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug, with flow not triggering Excel's recalculation routine. You might need to "hack it".

Make two spreadsheets (separate files). The master is linked and updated via Flow. The secondary spreadsheet links to the master via a normal file reference (e.g. [masterfile.xlsx]sheet1!A1) and contains the conditional formatting. If this doesn't work, try using Data > New query > From file > From Workbook instead of a normal file reference. Or can the output of the flow be dumped into an text file? Then use Data > From Text.
Using data sources means you can at least specify a refresh interval.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest check the type of value which comes from Flow.

Some times it happens that EXCEL grab strings instead numbers and vice-versa, in some cases also this can be tigered by real number accuracy problem.

So i suggest to update value from Flow to A1 cell, and make formatted reference in another cell A2.
Then check what will return ISNUMBER, ISTEXT, ISDATE ...
Try to cut the tail of real number by TRUNC( A1*1000 ) / 1000 , or use TEXT() before formatting this cell.